# ios5 "The operation could not be conpleted" when UIImagePickerController pick a 3gp file, and the whole UI freezed?

Tags: ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

Normal video file “choose” and "compressing videos", enter the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInof` callback.

But from "camera roll" pick one 3gp file, occur “The operation could not be completed”, and freezing, don't response to any input action. In the end, I am forced to close my app.

Comment: Same here. Implemented the picker as found in any example on the internet. But choosing [this example video](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/3gp/144/big_buck_bunny_144p_1mb.3gp) freezes the picker which then burns ~95% of the cpu until the app crashes. The strange thing is, that the default app on the system can display the video just fine. Were on iOS 9.3.2 by the way.

Comment: I also have same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is due to selection of bad video.
I got RID with the help of below code.

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(nonnull UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
if ([NSStringFromClass(viewController.class) isEqualToString:@"PUUIImageViewController"] == true){
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow isMemberOfClass:[UIWindow class]]){
        }else{

            //There is a bad video
            [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
        }
    });
}
```

}