# The operation could not be completed error using UIImagePickerControler

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController in a part of my app that allows the user to pick a video from the camera roll.  The problem I'm having is that when choosing certain specific videos from the image picker view controller at runtime, I get a dialog box saying "The operation could not be completed," and the app freezes.

The error and freeze occur as soon as you click on the video you want from the Camera Roll, and before you hit the "Choose" button -- so, when the error occurs, `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo()` has not yet been triggered.

The videos triggering the error are not corrupt files, as I can watch them just fine using my phone's Camera Roll app directly.

Here is the code I have in my project to set up the UIImagePickerViewController:

```
videoViewController = UIImagePickerController()
videoViewController.delegate = self
videoViewController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
videoViewController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String] 
videoViewController.allowsEditing = false
videoViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
```

The two files that are triggering this error do have one thing in common -- they both were texted to me from someone else's phone.  But if they are not corrupt, what could possibly be going on?

Comment: This is a well-known problem. Certain files just make the UIImagePickerController do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075650/ios5-the-operation-could-not-be-conpleted-when-uiimagepickercontroller-pick-a for example. File a bug with Apple...?

Comment: Given the fact that UIImagePickerController has been around for years and that the above issue would be a deal breaker to get your app in the App Store, that means no one in all these years has ever used UIImagePickerController in an app?  Too hard to believe.  There must be a workaround to this, or something I'm missing.

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. Another way is: UIImagePickerController has been around for years and has gotten buggier and creakier with every one of those years.

Comment: Could you post one of the "bad" files somewhere?

Comment: I found that the files triggering this error are of type .3gp.  However, this information was already in the one other Stack Overflow post about this problem, and I missed the detail about the file extension of the videos when I first saw that post.  So, I now know what it is about certain video files that is triggering the bug.  However, this does not help me because Apple's UIImagePickerController code is a black box -- there's no way for me to write a workaround other than to implement a homemade video picker controller.

Comment: matt, I'll award you the bounty points.  For me to do so, Stack Overflow requires that I wait 24 hours from the time I posted the bounty.

Comment: No, I don't want the bounty points. I want a workaround for the issue, just as you do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the question is that the video files that are triggering the error are all of type `.3gp`.

It turns out that knowledge of that fact is useless if I still want to use `UIPickerImageController` to let the user pick a video.  There's no way to control which video file types show up in `UIPickerImageController`, nor is there any way to add to Apple's code in order to convert a `.3gp` video to a different format in the time between when the user clicks on it in the `UIPickerImageController` and the time when the crash occurs.